# Hide Control depending on Item Index of ItemsControl

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

In my xaml I have a ItemsControl. Is is possible to have the ItemIndex property on ItemsControl? Basically I want to hide one of the child controls (TxtNodeData) if the Item index is 1

```
<ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding ConditionList}">
  <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
    <DataTemplate>
      <WrapPanel>
          <TextBlock Text="{Binding NodeData}" Name="TxtNodeData"/>
          <Button Content="+" />
          <ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding NodeNames}" DisplayMemberPath="name" SelectedValue="{Binding ConditionalNodeId, Mode=TwoWay}" SelectedValuePath="id"> </ComboBox>
          <Button Content="-" />
       </WrapPanel>
     </DataTemplate>
   </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
```

Comment: Sounds like a job for [`MultiValueConverter`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.imultivalueconverter.aspx). Convert to `Visibility`, bind to collection and item itself, search, if first index, then `Visibility.Hidden`...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could do it with combination of `AlternationCount` set to number of items in the list and trigger on `AlternationIndex` being 1

```
<ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding ConditionList}" AlternationCount="{Binding ConditionList.Count}">
    <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <WrapPanel>
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding NodeData}" Name="TxtNodeData">
                    <TextBlock.Style>
                        <Style TargetType="{x:Type TextBlock}">
                            <Style.Triggers>
                                <DataTrigger 
                                    Binding="{Binding 
                                        RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type ContentPresenter}}, 
                                        Path=(ItemsControl.AlternationIndex)}" 
                                    Value="1">
                                    <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Collapsed"/>
                                </DataTrigger>
                            </Style.Triggers>
                        </Style>
                    </TextBlock.Style>
                </TextBlock>
                <!-- other controls -->
            </WrapPanel>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
</ItemsControl>
```